# How to plot validation loss in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, faster-rcnn

I'd like to see validation loss in tesnorboard along with train loss. However I only see the train loss and the validation loss of the last checkpoint. I'm training a Faster R-CNN for object detection. I'm working in Google Colab. The code is:

```
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_config_path} \
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
    --checkpoint_every_n=2000 \
    --alsologtostderr \
    --num_train_steps=10000
```

```
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_config_path} \
    --model_dir={model_dir} \
    --checkpoint_dir={model_dir} \
```

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir {model_dir}
```

Thanks in adavnce

I've looked for a solution everywhere but I haven't found anything. I changed the config and added some parametres but they didn't work.